# How do I get the x coords to show up after mouse click? - Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to get the x coords to show up when the user clicks a point in the graphics window. Any ideas? Thanks!

Here's my code:

**Set graphics window**

```
win = GraphWin("Uncle Scrooges Money Bin", 640,480)
win.setCoords(0,0,80,60)
win.setBackground("white")
```

**Get coordinate of mouse click 1**

```
point1 = win.getMouse() #*****************************
```

**Display coordinates of point 1**

```
print("Point 1 coordinates: ", point1)
```

Comment: It would help if you indicated what framework you are using for windowing, and what the problem is with your code, what happens or doesn't?

Comment: Seems like he might be using this: http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics/node1.html

Comment: Also, what does it print in that last line?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to do what you say using `Tkinter` library.

```
import Tkinter

def mouse(event):
    print "Point 1 coordinate :",event.x,event.y
# event parameter will be passed to the function when the mouse is clicked
# This parameter also contains co-ordinates of where the mouse was clicked 
# which can be accessed by event.x and event.y

win = Tkinter.Tk()  # Main top-level window

win.title("Uncle Scrooges Money Bin")  
win.geometry("640x480+80+60")  # Set window diensions

frame = Tkinter.Frame(win, background='white', width=640, height=480)  
# New frame to handle mouse-clicks

frame.pack()  # pack frame(or make frame visible)
frame.bind('<Button-1>', mouse)  
# Bind mouse-click event denoted by '<Button-1>' to mouse function 

win.mainloop()  # Start window main loop
```