# Pillow, Tkinter, Python, Invisible image button

Tags: python, image, button, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Good evening all :)

So, ive been working on a little project of mine and ive come up with this code (with a little help from Sapphire64 :) )
I can display an image as a button to make it clickable but i have the problem of that you can see that it is a button, you can see the rectangular button box around the image.
I want the image to be clickable like a button but be essentially invisible.
I then tried making it into a checkbutton which pretty much works the same but again i had visible evidence of something other than just the image, the checkbutton. Could i make the checkbutton invisible?

So my question, how can i make a clickable image without it being obvious its a button/checkbutton.

Thanks!

Ive put my whole code here, you can see the image being displayed as both buttons, one is commented out.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

SWH = Tk() #Create Window

SWH.geometry("1024x950+130+0")
SWH.title("ServiceWhiz.")

img = None  #Var for future image named img. Currently giving it "None" as value.

def printimage():   #When print image is pressed do this:
    global img      #Make reference to predefined var.
    load = Image.open("ServiceWhiz.png")   #Load Image from file.
    render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)   #Load the image.

################################
    img = Checkbutton(SWH,state = ACTIVE,height = 45,width = 289,offvalue=0, image=render,command=imgpress)    #Display the image as a button and allow it to go to imgpress.
    #img = Button(SWH,image=render,command=imgpress)
################################
    img.image = render  
    img.place(x=0,y=0)
    return;

def imgpress():
    global img
    img.destroy()
    Label1 = Label(SWH, text="Image has been clicked",fg="#0094FF",font=('Arial',20)).pack()
    return;

SWTitle = Label(SWH, text="ServiceWhiz.",fg="#0094FF",font=('Arial',20)).pack()
MyButtonTest = Button(SWH, text="Click Me.",fg="White",bg="#0094FF",command=printimage).pack()
```

Comment: what you could do is get the x and y coordinates of a button click see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083720/how-do-i-get-the-x-coords-to-show-up-after-mouse-click-python/13440521#13440521 then you could test them to see if they are within certain boundaries and if so it does something, this would give an invisible button effectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to click on an image, just add a binding to `<Button-1>`. For example:

```
l = Label(..., image=render, ...)
...
def imgpress(event):
    ...
l.bind("<Button-1>", imgpress)
...
```

You can get the same effect by adding the image to a canvas and binding on the canvas.

Comment: Ah! this is useful, got it working nicely now, thanks very much :)